# Is it possible to write an rxjs operator that controls subscription to it's source?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-subscriptions

Let's say I have an observable `source` that has the following properties:

- It makes a network request the first time it's subscribed to
- It's idempotent, so it will always emit the same value after it's first subscribed to
- It's low priority, so we don6t6 want to be too eager in subscribing to it

What would be ideal is if there were some sort of operator `delaySubscriptionUntil` that would delay subscription until some other observable `s` emits a value.

So for example:

```
const s = new Subject<void>();
const l = source
  .pipe(
    delaySubscriptionUntil(s));

l.subscribe(console.log);
// The above won't print anything until this line executes
s.next();
```

I looked through the documentation to see if there's an existing operator like this, but haven't found one.

Answer (score 1):

You just put the subject first and switchMap

```
const l = s.pipe(
  switchMap(() => source)
);
```

Once the subject emits then the source will be subscribed to.

Any thing that is after wont work as it relies on the previous observable emitting a value. You can have a filter in the chain that stops the previous observable's emission being emitted but there is nothing you can pass back up the chain to control outer subscriptions.

You could use a takeWhile

```
let allow = false;

const l = source.pipe(
  takeWhile(allow)
);
```

but here the subscription to source is active, it is emitting values, they are just stopped from being passed through.

So you could make a similar operator that keeps an internal flag and is flipped by a subject but source is still going to be emitting, you are just filtering values. You could buffer up the values if you don't want to lose them.

Comment: The `takeWhile` solution wouldn't work because the idea would be to prevent the source observable from doing the side effects it has to do to emit any values.

Comment: Which is why I have put it in there and explained how anything in the pipe chain relies on the source emitting a value before it is invoked. You will need to have the subject earlier in the chain not later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`share()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/share) which will share the result of anything that happened before it until you call `sub.next()` with a new url then the request will happen again.

```js
const sub = new BehaviorSubject<string>('http://example.com/api');
const result$ = sub.pipe(
  exhaustMap(url => this.http.get(url)),
  share()
)

// Each one of these subscriptions will share the result.
// The http request will be called only once
// until you send a new url to the BehaviorSubject.
result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```